# Select a Schedule (or other elements) by name instead of index number in Dynamo/Revit

Tags: revit-api

I have a dynamo script that exports schedules out of Revit. It uses a bit of Python also, (not relevant to this question, but I thought I would just include it all).
It all works great, but I notice if certain schedules get deleted from Revit, it could change the "Index" number of the schedules I need to export. I would like to use the schedule name instead of the dynamo index number, as this will help me maintain the connection without checking if it's exporting the correct schedule. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution that works well. Using the "==" node and "List.FilterByBoolMask" node I was able to filter down to just what's in the String. Now I can set the string node to be an input for the dynamo player and user just needs to input the exact name of their schedule. Thank you Michael Kilkelly from ArchSmarter for this helpful video.
[How to Dynamo: Filter List by Element Name](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2ocG-yUleQ)

[image: Final Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

From the pure Revit API point of view I can only answer that yes, this is possible. You are calling the [`ViewSchedule.Export` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/8ba18e73-6daf-81b6-d15b-e4aa90bc8c22.htm). The `ViewSchedule` element can indeed be retrieved from the Revit database by name using a filtered element collection.